# tns --watch not working

Tags: typescript, nativescript, tns

So a few days i started this app and --watch was working just fine until today.

This is what i call: `tns run android --emulator --device=ANDROID --watch`

but when i change code, nothing happens, my changes are not present.
When i run tns doctor, it shows that everything is up to date except ios emulator( witch i am not using at this time ).

Just tried to reinstall the app( from git - https://github.com/nestor94/my-instagram ) and re-created the avd. still --watch not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong [command](https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-1#15-development-workflow) to watch for changes try using `tns livesync android --watch`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "wrong"

> Since {N} 2.5.0 we say:
>   This command is deprecated. It will be removed in the next version of NativeScript CLI. Use the "run" command instead.

I suggest that you run `tns run --help` and see if you have a `--watch` flag .. I don't see such. and from my experience, it's syncing changes by default ( unless you're adding new libs/installs and then you need to quit & run this command again )