# failed to load module tns_modules/application/application.js

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript, tns

I have hitting my head on this for past 3 hours.

What i call: `../../latest-cli/nativescript-cli/bin/tns run android --watch --device=emulator-5554`

[image]

Some ideas would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have all of the latest parts of NativeScript (core modules, runtime, and CLI). There's a great blog post here: http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=323 which outlines that all of the above need to be in sync. Then you should try running `tns platform remove android` then `tns platform add android`. Then make sure you uninstall this failed build, and install a fresh build after adding the platform back.

Also just open the emulator and call `tns livesync android --watch` and the CLI will detect the running emulator. No need to specify.

Comment: Another thing is the `--watch` param does not work with `tns run android|ios` this is not the [first time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446017/tns-watch-not-working) i noticed you tried using it with `run`

Comment: I ussualy use livesync.

But yeah, i followed the instructions, still no luck. ;/ also tryed to remove platform etc. Maybe you need more info ?